# Python control "with" context manager with conditional

Tags: python, python-2.7, conditional-statements, with-statement

Can Python2.7 use a conditional to control a "with" context manager?  My scenario is that if a gzipped file exists, I want to append to it, and if it does not exist, I want to write to a new file.  The pseudo code is:

```
with gzip.open(outfile, 'a+') if os.isfile(outfile) else with open(outfile, 'w') as outhandle:
```

Or...

```
if os.isfile(outfile):
    with gzip.open(outfile, 'a+') as outhandle:
        # do stuff
else:
    with open(outfile, 'w') as outhandle:
        # do the same stuff
```

I don't want to repeat the "do stuff" since it will be the same between them.  But how can I use a conditional to control the with context?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to use context manager conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928590/pythonic-way-to-use-context-manager-conditionally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that functions can also be assigned to variables

```
if os.isfile(outfile):
    open_function = gzip.open
    mode = 'a+'
else:
    open_function = open
    mode = 'w'

with open_function(outfile, mode) as outhandle:
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try just writing a function for the "do stuff"

```
def do_stuff():
    #do stuff here 

if os.isfile(outfile):
    with gzip.open(outfile, 'a+') as outhandle:
        do_stuff()
else:
    with open(outfile, 'w') as outhandle:
        do_stuff()
```

Comment: Good point, and I have done that in other places.  But I'm wondering if there is a way to do it in the with statement.